# Is there a way to tell SSLStreams to validate the remote certificate based on the certificate present in path rather than Windows keystore?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

When using SSLStreams with AuthenticateAsClient, i think RemoteCertificateValidationCallback function checks if the public key of the server certificate is present in the "Trusted Root Certification Authority" of Windows Keystore, if not present then the SSLPolicyErrors gets updated.

Now is there a way to say to SSLStreams that try to validate the Server certificate based on the public key present in a directory rather than Windows keystore.